# Java method syntax

Tags: java

I'm quite the programming beginner. I'm learning about methods and I want to know the difference between those two. Why can't I use my self made method the same way text.length(); is being used?

```
text.length();

text.selfMadeMethod(); instead of selfMadeMethod(text);
```

Edit: It seems miss wrote my example above, I'm sorry. I'll post the exercise I was working on so it can show more clearly what I tried to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReversingText {
public static String reverse(String text) {
    int x = text.length() -1;
    String reverse = "";
    while (x >= 0) {

        reverse += text.charAt(x);
        x--;

    }
    return reverse;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type in your text: ");
    String text = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("In reverse order: " + reverse(text));
    System.out.println("In reverse order: " + text.reverse());
    }
}
```

The last print statement was just me trying that, the exercise didn't ask me to do it. Again I'm sorry if this is either a stupid question or unclear, thanks.

Comment: Because that's how the language is designed. You can't add arbitrary methods to an existing class (without extending, which isn't possible for `final` classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I use my self made method the same way text.length(); is being used?

because you need an *object* to call a method on.

But you did not create an object of your class `ReversingText`.

An object is created by invoking the `new` operator followed by a class name (more precisely a constructor of the class)

```
new ReversingText();
```

But the method you wrote has the `static` keyword which means it is accessible via the class name directly:

```
ReversingText.reverse("some string");
```

you don't need to write that in your code because you are in the same class where you can omit the class name.

if you want to use your own method like `text.length()` you have to do 3 things:

1. remove the `static` key word from the method signature.
2. create an instance of `ReversingText` and store it in a variable in main:
   `ReversingText reversingText = new ReversingText();`
3. call your method on that variable:
   `reversingText.reverse("some string");`

Answer (score 3):

Because Java `String` has [`String.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--) (and doesn't have a `reverse(String)` method), and it is a `final` class (that means you cannot sub-class it to add custom methods). It is worth mentioning, but not directly to your question, that there is already a [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--) method.

Answer (score 2):

This is about the semantics of java.

```
public class SomeClass{
    public void someMethod(){

    }
}
```

The above code basically means `SomeClass` has a method `someMethod` that any instance can use in the following way:

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
s.someMethod();
```

`someMethod` is called an instance-method of `SomeClass`. This means `someMethod` is part of any instance of the class `SomeClass`.

On the other hand

```
public void anotherMethod(SomeClass s){

}
```

means `anotherMethod` accepts an instance of class `SomeClass` as parameter and could be called like this:

```
anotherMethod(new SomeClass());
```

Note the difference between "instance method" and "parameter".

Classes are immutable from the outside. This means the only place where you can add methods to a class is directly within the definition of the respective class.

Answer (score 1):

Alas you cannot reopen classes in Java.

`text` is a string and you can only send messages to a string that are defined in the `String` class. Alas you cannot the `String` class extend it with your own functions. This is an unfortunate limitation of Java. Other languages like Ruby allow classes to be reopened.

The common way work around this limitation is to create a `StringUtils` class with a static `reverse` function and then use it as follows

```
StringUtils.reverse(text)
```

Comment: Others might consider it fortunate. No need to editorialize.

Answer (score 1):

When you call on a method by placing it AFTER the class/instance name, this indicates you are calling on a method that belongs to that class. Some examples:

- `text.length()` calls the method `length()` in class `String` (which `text` is an instance of), using the values assigned to `text`.
- `Math.random()` calls the static method `random()` in class `Math`.

The class which the method belongs to must be specified before the name of the method itself. If no class is specified, it is assumed to belong to the same class which it is called in.

This is why, in your example, it works the first way but not the second. `reverse(text)` calls on the `reverse(String)` method in the current class, passing `text` to it as an argument. `text.reverse()` calls on the `reverse()` method in class `String`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about a very well known language feature, aka Pimp My Library. Some languages like Scala, Kotlin, C#,... already have this syntax. But unfortunately, Java does not have it just yet.